# How to do that when you scroll to a specific page position, function is started once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

There `scrl` function that triggers another function (element movement in the page `ring` function ), if we have scrolled to a certain position. But only if we scroll the page again, the element, after finish, will not stop and will continue to change its position, it is a function of `ring` continues to run.

- how to stop the execution of the function?
- how to make that `ring` function is performed only once at the time
  worked as a condition?
- how to write the condition that triggers the function once?

```js
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  hh = parseInt($('.wrapdiv').css('height'));

function ring() {
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //1
      left: 187,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2
      left: 300,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2.1
      left: 394,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').animate({ //3
      left: 481,
      top: 100,
    },
    800);
};


function scrl() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > ((h + hh) / 2)) {
    ring();
  }
  
  
// Inside the function can be a lot of other functions and I need to stop only ring()
};



function myfoo() {
  $('.firstdiv').css('height', h);
};
$(window).scroll(scrl);
$(window).resize(myfoo);
$(document).ready(myfoo);
```

```css
.parentring {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #DCDCDC;
  border: 4px solid #F1F1F1;
  left: 87px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #006492, inset 0 0 7px #153F53;
}
.wrapdiv {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 244px;
  background: #CE93D8;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.firstdiv {
  background: #FFB74D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="wrapdiv">Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что укрепление и развитие структуры влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
  обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия.
 зации соответствующий условий активизации. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение новых предложений. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры требуют
  от нас анализа системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Не следует,
  однако забывать, что сложившаяся структура организации позволяет оценить значение дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! консультация с широким активом позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Равным
  образом рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет оценить значение системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.

</div>
<div class="parentring">
  <div class="ring"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should access DOM elements after the DOM tree is loaded.
 Place all the elements "selection" operations(getting by id or other selector) into `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` function (for pure Javascript - into `window.onload = function(){ ... }`).
To prevent repeated `ring()` function execution within `scrl` function use some global variable or function object static property(to indicate if `ring` function was executed). I would prefer the second approach:

```
function scrl() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (!scrl.wasRinged && top > ((h + hh) / 2)) {
    ring();
    scrl.wasRinged = true;
  }
  ...
}
scrl.wasRinged = false;  // defining static property on function object
```

Comment: !scrl.wasRinged вот это если на человеческом что значит?

Comment: Только что решил с помощью i=0... return i++... if(i<1.... Но альтернативные решения тоже не помешают)

Comment: !scrl.wasRinged - It's Logical NOT (!). http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Да нет, это я понимаю, просто никогда не приходилось использовать такое, да мне вообще много чего использовать еще не приходилось.)) просто не совсем понял, каким образом проверяется, что функция уже была запущена ранее. С помощью глобальной переменной-то понял, а вот второй вариант не совсем, надо будет завтра попробовать переварить))

Comment: второй вариант оптимальней, так как не засоряет глобальную область видимости. При начальном объявлении функции будет также инициализированно свойство `wasRinged`. При самом первом скроле и срабатывании условия - выполнится функция `ring` и свойство `wasRinged` получит значение `true`. При всех последующих "скролах" условие не выполниться и функция `ring` не будет вызвана повторно, так как `!scrl.wasRinged`  вернёт `false`

Comment: То есть можно было написать if(scrl.wasRinged = false.... Вместо if(!scrl.wasRinged.... И все бы тоже работало, верно?

Comment: только так: `scrl.wasRinged === false`, технически - да, но логические операторы придумали не зря. Используй их почаще, и через время ощутишь их пользу, наглядность и лаконичность

Comment: Благодарю, я за перфекционизм в коде, так что стараюсь по возможности делать все правильно))

Comment: и что? ошибка связана с предложенным ранее решением ... или всё-таки указывает на что-то другое ?

Comment: знал бы я на что она указывает) но в коде ошибок нет?